# i want implement ICO Contract for token contract

Tags: cryptography, solidity, cryptocurrency, erc20, bep20

I have some simple ico contracts for airdrop and presale
with lock token future to lock token until ico end
and I want to know how to connect it to token contract

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way for doing this the first is to create new wallet and put all presale token in the new wallet and then give allowance for the ico contract to controle this wallet and after this do methods for recieve ethers in the contract and transfer from the wallet of presale
Second way is to send the token into the contract and send from  the contract token

Comment: so you have any simple contract for presale 
and how I must connect it to my token contract